# How to update/change last row for all conditional rules' ranges

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, conditional-formatting

Here are our conditional formatting rules:

[image]

The actual scenario is much more complex although the first row of each `AppliesTo` range is always 5.

Once new data has been imported the last row of each `AppliesTo` range could change to say 15.

**How can we apply this change using `vba` ?**

This is our current loop that finds each `AppliesTo` range:

```
Sub updateAllCondFormatRules()

    Dim x As Excel.FormatCondition
    Dim r As Range

    Dim lastRw  As Integer
    Dim newLastRw  As Integer
    newLastRw = 15

    For Each x In ActiveSheet.Cells.FormatConditions
        Set r = x.AppliesTo
        MsgBox r.Address

        '>>here we need to change r so that the new last row is equal to newLastRw

        x.ModifyAppliesToRange r
    Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had an issue with the type of `x` object, but this code seems to work :

```
Sub updateAllCondFormatRules()

    Dim x As Excel.FormatCondition
    Dim r As Range
    Dim lastRw  As Long
    Dim newLastRw  As Long

    newLastRw = 20

    For Each x In ActiveSheet.Cells.FormatConditions
        Set r = x.AppliesTo

        MsgBox r.Address
        '>>here we need to change r so that the new last row is equal to newLastRw
        'Set r = ActiveSheet.Range(Replace(r.Address, Split(r.Address, "$")(UBound(Split(r.Address, "$"))), newLastRw))
        Set r = r.Resize(newLastRw - r.Cells(1, 1).Row + 1, r.Columns.Count)
        MsgBox r.Address

        x.ModifyAppliesToRange r
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: ok - well that works (so uppped): although I was assuming the answer would be a little more elegant using `Offset` and `Resize`?

Comment: Hehe, sorry for the dirty simplicity, I'll think about the `resize` and try to find a solution with it! ;)

Comment: @whytheq : It is indeed much more cleaner with resize! Give this one a try ;)

Comment: ha - thought I'd asked too much: thanks much tidier than mucking around with strings.

Comment: No problem, and you didn't ask much, just for me to step out of my habits/confort zone but it wasn't that horrible don't worry ;)